# multiple select statements on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have trouble to make this multiple select statement.

this is example if i select *. in the reportsto column it's ID for another Employee.
and i want to display firstname and lastname of this emplyee in this column

```
empID   FName  LName ReportsTo
1         te    xxxx     6
6         aaa   asfa     1
5         zzz   xxxx     6
4         ttt   asfa     1




this how i want to display it on my gridview
empID   FName  LName ReportsTo
1         te    xxxx     aaa asfa      
6         aaa   asfa     te xxxx
5         zzz   xxxx     te xxxx
4         ttt   asfa     aaa asfa
```

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the table by itself in order to get the name of the user reports with. The query below uses `INNER JOIN` and it will show all the users with values of `reportsTo`. But if somehow column `reportsTo` is *nullable* and youw ant to show all users, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.Fname TO_Fname,
        b.LName TO_F_NAME
FROM    emp a
        INNER JOIN emp b
            ON a.reportsTo = b.empID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

if you want to concatenate the two columns,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.Fname + ' ' + b.LName Report_TO_Name
FROM    emp a
        INNER JOIN emp b
            ON a.reportsTo = b.empID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96499/1)

Comment: Thank you so much it work. i have one emp has null on the reportsto column do you know how to still show his record but no thing in the reportto column

Comment: I really appreciate. all your help so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Null reports to, you may use "Left Join" instead of "Inner Join"

select C.empID, C.FName, C.LName, T.FName + ' '  + T.LName Report_TO_Name
from emp C left join emp T on (c.reportsTo = T.empID)